# Обновить поля объекта

Tags: scala

Есть класс NewBorn:

```
case class NewBorn(
   name: String,
   parents: Seq[String],
   bornTime: Option[DateTime] = None
   inList: Boolean = false
) {
  def updated(newBorn: NewBorn) = ???
}
```

как реализовать метод updated для обновления полей объекта из объекта, который будет принят методом?

Comment: В вашем объекте поля не изменяемые. Добавьте `var` и сможете присваивать значения.

Comment: Непонятно зачем Вам это. У [case классов](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) же есть метод `copy`

Answer (score 0):

Ваш класс имеет неизменяемые поля, это значит что их нельзя изменить.

У вас два варианта:

- сделать поля изменяемыми
- возвращать новый экземпляр (Это не имеет смысла так как новый экземпляр будет полностью равен параметру).